# Redirect user to where they were after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

We have successfully implemented OpenID Connect using Microsoft Identity on our ASP.NET Core v5 web site.  It logs in and logs out perfectly, except that it would be great if we can find a way to redirect users back to the page they were on and not just one of the configured Redirect URI's in Azure Active Directory for the application.

The site that is being created will have hundreds of pages so it's not possible to add them all to the Redirect URI's section.

I can't seem to find any documentation that supports passing the relative URL to Microsoft to return the user back to the specific page they were on.

Comment: Generally, you'd have the redirect uri be a gateway page that has a query param (or a header, or cookie, pick your poison) that tells what page to go back to. You pass the returnUrl as a query param along the way to auth and it basically just echoes it back. Your redirect page then can response.redirect as needed and according to whatever framework you're using.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) showing some `returnUrl` stuff

Comment: From your description, I assume you want to get the "return url" and then redirect to the previous page after authentication. If that is the case, in the previous page, you could get current page url, then pass it via the query string method (put the returnurl at the end of the redirect url (authentication redirect)). Then, in the authentication valid method, after validation, you could check whether the return url is null or not, then redirect to the page.

Comment: More detail information about the return url, you could refer the following links: [Back to previous page - ASP.NET CORE](https://forums.asp.net/t/2143325.aspx?Back+to+previous+page+ASP+NET+CORE) and [Working with return url in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809363/working-with-return-url-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think any of these will work.  We're using Microsoft's OpenID Connect and it handles the login/logout functions.  Here's an example of the way the logout works: `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut" asp->Sign out</a>` and ?returnUrl doesn't seem to get returned once the user comes back from authenticating their account with Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `redirectUri=/your-local-uri` as a query string to `SignIn`. As you can see in the code below, ActionController will redirect in this case. The uri needs to be local (for example `/local-uri`)

`Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Areas.MicrosoftIdentity.Controllers.ActionController.cs`

```
 public IActionResult SignIn(
        [FromRoute] string scheme,
        [FromQuery] string redirectUri)
    {
        scheme ??= OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        string redirect;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri) && Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUri))
        {
            redirect = redirectUri; // <-- /your-local-uri
        }
        else
        {
            redirect = Url.Content("~/")!;
        }

        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirect },
            scheme);
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70265052/8645224), in case you are using the standard "" link with microsoft identity, you can use the asp-route-redirectUri tag, such as:

```
<a asp-area="microsoftidentity" asp-controller="account" asp-action="signin" asp-route-redirectUri="/whatever">Sign In</a>
```

You could use ViewBag, TempData, Model, etc to replace "whatever".